# nodejs handle form created in loop

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

Trying to learn Node.JS through coding PC Games Store Prototype.
I show every game which is in my MySQL database on Main page.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  database.connection.query("select * from games", function(err, rows, fields){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    res.render('main', {rows: rows});
});
```

HTML:

```
<% for (var i = rows.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { %>
  <form method="post" action="/buyItem">
    <div style="float:left;" class="Game">
      <div class="text">
        <label><%= rows[i].name %></label> <br>
        <label><%= rows[i].category %></label>
      </div>
      <img src="<%= rows[i].image %>"> <br>
      <label><%= rows[i].price %> </label> <br>
      <button type="submit" class="button">Purchase</button>
      <br> <br> <br> 
    </div>
  </form>
  <% } %>
```

How can I implement post method for this situation? How do I know which submit button is pressed so I can add this game to user's bucket? (bucket is not implemented yet)
Maybe I should create new action for every game on the page? Like `<form mathod="post" action="/buyItem <% + i %>">` but still how can I catch these actions?

Answer (score 1):

You can create only single form. and On button click, get the id of the game and execute function for purchase.

```
<form mathod="post" action="/buyItem">

for (var i = rows.length-1; i >= 0; i--){ 
<div style="float:left;" class="Game">
  <div class="text">
    <label><%= rows[i].name %></label> <br>
    <label><%= rows[i].category %></label>
  </div>
  <img src="<%= rows[i].image %>"> <br>
  <label><%= rows[i].price %> </label> <br>
  <button type="submit" class="button" onclick="purchase(rows[i].id)">Purchase</button>
  <br> <br> <br> 
</div> }  

</form>
```

Comment: Where should I execute function for purchase? In post method? How can I transfer `rows[i].id` to post? I think it should be like `purchase = function(id){
 console.log(id);
} ` and `router.post('/buyItem', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next, id){
 purchase(id);
});
`